# Load external <script> without cache using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to load an external javascript file into the page and make sure its not cached. I do not have access to php so I cant generate a random string after the filename.

In PHP the script would look like this:

```
<script src="http://site.com/cool.js?<?php echo $randomnumber; ?>"></script>
```

Is there a way to do something like that using only javascript?

Comment: You can configure your server to set appropriate headers. It's not possible to do it from the browser side.

Comment: Does the script tag already exist? or are you adding a new script tag with javascript.

Comment: Use jQuery's $.getScript and append a random string to the end of the filename - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: @JayBlanchard ah - I interpreted "I do not have access to php" to mean "I do not have access to the source"; if the page code can be changed then yes that will work fine.

Comment: @JayBlanchard getScript already does that. From the docs: *Be default, $.getScript() sets the cache setting to false. This appends a timestamped query parameter to the request URL to ensure that the browser downloads the script each time it is requested*

Comment: I had forgotten that @epascarello, thanks!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use jQuery's [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead of a script tag.

```
$.getScript("http://example.com/cool.js");
```

or pure JavaScript

```
var scr = document.createElement("script");
scr.src = "http://example.com/cool.js" + "?ts=" + new Date().getTime();
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scr);
```

Comment: Awesome!!! I was beating my head against the wall trying to figure out how to get Edge to stop caching. None of the anti-caching HTTP headers were working. "?ts=" is brilliant!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool solution but: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ANYVAR is not defined". Seems the JS file is loaded after other <scripts> although JQuery.Ready :/

Comment: @Extrangeplanet of course it will be loaded AFTER ready

Answer (score 5):

Just append a random string to the `src` of the script like you do with PHP. For this you need to inject the `<script>` tag with JS.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'path/to/file?' + new Date().getMilliseconds();

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
```

Comment: FYI: getMilliseconds() can repeat if you are really lucky.

Comment: Valid point to some extent, but chances are really low since you don't repeat this operation many many times within the same context (browser, time, etc.).

Comment: The birthday paradox says that with as few as 32 requests, there is a 50% chance that a value repeats. The fact that the request isn't issued very often just means that if a repeated value *does* match a cached version, it is *more* likely to be an old version of the script rather than a recent version. Better to use a longer string, like `getTime()` that could only repeat over a very short time frame. `getMilliseconds()` is effectively just a **very** low-entropy random number when used this way.

Comment: You are absolutely right in that this exact way of doing this does not guarantee a good level of uniqueness. (So you might end up receiving a cached copy of the script if the appended random happens to be the same as a previous value.) My goal here was not to provide sufficient uniqueness. But anyway, here is a better random to add to the request URL: `parseInt(Math.random().toString().substr(-5))`

Comment: @marekful Why wouldn't I repeat this operation 1000 times in the same browser session? If my server is providing periodic real-time updates, then it would take only a few minutes to reach 1000.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just insert a script tag into the DOM, with JS generating the value, e.g.

```
var d = new Date.getTime();
$('head').append('<scri' + 'pt src="http://....?cachebuster=' + d + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store" />`. There is another ticket talking about this: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers)

Comment: I think this is for the whole page. Not for a single JavaScript resource.