# html javascript loading external scripts

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to dynamically add an external script tag to my html as follows:

**html**

```
<html>
        <head>
                <script src="js/load-scripts.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form>
                Load scripts NOW!!<br/>
                <input type="text" onclick="downScripts(); testCall();" value="Click to Load scripts and test" />
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**load-scripts.js**

```
function downScripts() {
    var element = document.createElement("SCRIPT");
    element.src = "js/try-catch.js";
    element.defer = false;
    console.log(element);
    document.body.appendChild(element);
 }
```

When I click on the button, the js/try-catch.js file gets added to the Sources in chrome dev tools, but when I try to call one function from try-catch.js - which is defined in  try-catch.js (like testCall() below)

**try-catch.js**

```
function testCall() {
    alert('scripts imported from try catch js external');
}
```

If the external javascript has been added (i see it in developer tools), why am i not able to call one of it's functions- I get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: testCall is not defined

Comment: You need to use event delegation method...

Comment: do i have to use .delegate() method in jquery??

Comment: I mean instead of onclick attribute use addEventListener.... and obviously you can do it with jquery method too @Prabhas...

Comment: I think your external javascript doesn't load properly. First answer for this question can help you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897849/load-external-script-without-cache-using-javascript

Comment: Why don't you just use [SystemJs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs) or likes?

Answer (score 0):

The `testCall` function is called earlier than try-catch.js is loaded.