# JS scripts do not refresh on the web page when I upload them to the server

Tags: javascript, html, vps

I'm working on web page, which is created on VPS, (I don't know if it has somenthing common with this, but I bought domain name on sav.com and using certbot for SSL), and when I'm uploading JS files to the server, they does not refresh. I was trying `ctrl + F5`, but it works only once, when I'm uploading again I can't refresh anything.
What should I do, to see the newest verions of scripts that I uploaded on server?

Comment: Your browser caches the files.
I think this link is useful: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897849/load-external-script-without-cache-using-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897849/load-external-script-without-cache-using-javascript)

Comment: @SoroushBgm thanks, it is loading with time stamp at the end of js script name, idk if its optimal because, now I need to change imports in all html files, but it's only working solution for me